# Spring Stomp @SendToUser with unauthenticated user not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I'm trying to respond to an unauthenticated user using `@SendToUser`.

- Spring 4.1.1

I'm using a newly created Spring Boot application and the only config I have is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp").withSockJS();
    }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user"); 
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
@MessageMapping("/search")
@SendToUser("/search")
public String search(@Payload String xxx) {
    return "TEST1234";
}
```

---

JS:

```
var socket = new SockJS('/webapp/stomp');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    stompClient.subscribe('/user/search', function(data){
        alert(data.body);
    });
});
```

Spring output:

```
DEBUG  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: 996 - Successfully completed request
DEBUG   o.s.w.s.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator:  45 - New WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=shizav88]
DEBUG       o.s.m.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler: 158 - Processing CONNECT session=shizav88
DEBUG      o.s.m.simp.user.UserDestinationMessageHandler: 187 - Translated /user/search -> [/search-usershizav88]
```

JS:

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
stompClient.send("/app/search", {}, "test"));
```

Spring output:

```
DEBUG     o.s.m.s.a.s.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler: 348 - Searching methods to handle SEND /app/search session=shizav88
DEBUG     o.s.m.s.a.s.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler: 446 - Invoking de.benneq.next.search.SearchController#search[1 args]
DEBUG   o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 247 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'searchController'
DEBUG      o.s.m.simp.user.UserDestinationMessageHandler: 187 - Translated /user/shizav88/search -> [/search-usershizav88]
```

---

To me it looks like Spring maps the subscription to `/search-usershizav88`. And then uses `/search-usershizav88` to send the response. But my JS client does not receive anything.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now I got it working, but I don't really know **WHY**:

### Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp").withSockJS();
    }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic"); // <- added "/queue"
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user"); 
    }
}
```

### Controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/search")
@SendToUser // <- maps to "/user/queue/search"
public String search(@Payload String xxx) {
    return "TEST1234";
}
```

### JS:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/search', function(data){
    alert(data.body);
});
```

### Spring output:

```
DEBUG  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: 996 - Successfully completed request
DEBUG   o.s.w.s.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator:  45 - New WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=fkbmnpkj]
DEBUG       o.s.m.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler: 158 - Processing CONNECT session=fkbmnpkj
DEBUG      o.s.m.simp.user.UserDestinationMessageHandler: 187 - Translated /user/queue/search -> [/queue/search-userfkbmnpkj]
DEBUG       o.s.m.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler: 175 - Processing SUBSCRIBE /queue/search-userfkbmnpkj id=sub-0 session=fkbmnpkj
```

Now there's an additional line in the log, which says that it is **Processing SUBSCRIBE /queue/search-userfkbmnpkj id=sub-0 session=fkbmnpkj**

That was missing before.

It would still be nice, if someone could explain why I need the `/queue` mapping for this to work properly.

Comment: What the UserDestinationResolver makes is removing '/user' prefix. Then in the non-working case the destination remianed was '/search/{'user'+userSessionId}', but '/search' is filtered out, because there was not simpleBroker is enabled there.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to adding **"/queue"** here `registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic"); // <- added "/queue"`

Comment: How did you enable all this debug output - my spring isn't posting much

Answer (score 1):

In first post you subscribe at "/user/search".
In second "/user/queue/search".
I checked "/user/topic/search" and it also works.
So solution is to use valid topic name. No magic...